# How to read RFID reader output only in my c# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, rfid

I am using a HID RFID Reader(125Khz) for the first time in my c# application. This RFID reader is providing output as keyboard input. As I am able to fetch the value of RFIDs by processing values on HID Keyboard's key event but the problem is that, when my c# application is minimised, my application is getting RFID's value but this value is also getting posted to any writable field/file, if it is opened. For example: In Notepad or Broswer Address field.

In short, I want RFID reader value only in c# application whether it is minimised or not. Thank you.

Also, help me to know if we can stop RFID reader behaving like HID keyboard and getting values noramlly.

Answer (score 1):

Which rfid reader are you using?
In HID Mode it is not possible to avoid that reader is writing in active textfield which has the focus (notepad). You have to disable HID mode and enable serial-mode or something like that. There are many readers on the market, do you need especially the 125khz reader? whats about UHF or HF readers like that ones: https://www.sydesoft.de/stationaere-rfid-reader.html